# How can I get arrows to attach to outside of rectangle split in a graphdrawing layout?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to make use of the newer (pgf > 3.0) graphdrawing layouts to do class diagrams, but I can't seem to figure out how to get arrows to attach to the outline of a rectangle split. I've read about the anchor points for a rectangle split in the documentation at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf, but I can't figure out how to make use of them.

Basically, in the example below the arrows should attach at the outside of the rectangle split. I have no idea why they are attaching instead to the middle "two" box. Any ideas?

[image: example]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,arrows,shapes.multipart}
\usegdlibrary{layered}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{object/.style={draw, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
    rounded corners, rectangle split part align={center,left,left}},
    align=left}
\def \properties {\nodepart{two}}
\def \methods {\nodepart{three}}

\begin{tikzpicture} [layered layout, >=latex]

\node(obj)[object] {
obj
\properties
+property: class
\methods
method(inputs): outputs};

\node(foo)[object] {
foo
\properties
ids: cell array\\
xyz: Nx3 array
\methods
compute():\\
plot(): handle
};

\node(bar)[object] {
bar
\properties
ids: cell array\\
xyz: Nx3 array
\methods
compute():\\
plot(): handle
};

\graph[use existing nodes]
{
(obj) -> (foo);
(foo) -> [>=open diamond] (bar);
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think `layered layout` is intended to be used for positioning nodes outside of the `\graph` command. If you explicitly position the nodes using the `at` syntax and remove the `layered layout` from the picture options, the connections use the expected anchors.

Comment: This is what I was beginning to suspect, Mark, that anchors were somehow incompatible with algorithmic graphdrawing. But  the automatic layout algorithms of PGF 3.0 are exactly what I'm hoping to leverage to make class diagrams in latex. I know there are packages which do class diagrams in latex out there, but from what I've seen they don't have compact syntaxes and/or don't do automatic layout.

Answer (score 1):

Forest doesn't draw graphs, but it does automatically arrange nodes in trees and the syntax used to specify the contents can be (almost) as compact as you like.

`object tree` retains much of the current syntax for specifying node content:

```
\begin{forest}
  object tree
  [obj \properties +property: class \methods method(inputs): outputs
    [foo \properties ids: cell array\\
    xyz: Nx3 array \methods compute():\\
    plot(): handle
      [bar \properties ids: cell array\\
      xyz: Nx3 array \methods compute():\\
      plot(): handle, edge+=-open diamond
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

`object tree auto` uses `|` as a delimiter to split the content of each nodes into the three parts of the vertically split node:

```
\begin{forest}
  object tree auto
  [obj | +property: class | method(inputs): outputs
    [foo | ids: cell array\\
    xyz: Nx3 array | compute():\\
    plot(): handle
      [bar | ids: cell array\\
      xyz: Nx3 array | compute():\\
      plot(): handle, edge+=-open diamond
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

The output is the same in both cases:

[image: class diagrams as Forest trees?]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/704954/ addaswyd o gwestiwn Nick: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233419/
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.multipart}
\tikzset{object/.style={draw,  rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
    rounded corners, rectangle split part align={center,left,left}},
    align=left}
\def \properties {\nodepart{two}}
\def \methods {\nodepart{three}}

\forestset{%
  object tree/.style={%
    for tree={object,edge+={-latex},l sep*=1.5}
  },
  object tree auto/.style={
    object tree,
    before typesetting nodes={%
      for tree={%
        temptoksb=,
        split option={content}{|}{content',temptoksa,temptoksb},
        content+={\properties},
        content+/.register=temptoksa,
        content+={\methods},
        content+/.register=temptoksb,
      },
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  object tree
  [obj \properties +property: class \methods method(inputs): outputs
    [foo \properties ids: cell array\\
    xyz: Nx3 array \methods compute():\\
    plot(): handle
      [bar \properties ids: cell array\\
      xyz: Nx3 array \methods compute():\\
      plot(): handle, edge+=-open diamond
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  object tree auto
  [obj | +property: class | method(inputs): outputs
    [foo | ids: cell array\\
    xyz: Nx3 array | compute():\\
    plot(): handle
      [bar | ids: cell array\\
      xyz: Nx3 array | compute():\\
      plot(): handle, edge+=-open diamond
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```